# Can't start wso2 identity server,just flash and view nothing

Tags: wso2

Yesterday I can still start the identity server,but today when I start the server,the console flash ，and then nothing happened,anyone who view these before?

Comment: Can you please explain bit more .. are their any back end errors? any other observation, changes you have done ect.

Comment: well,when I click the wso2server.bat to start the server that day,the cosole show for a second and then shutdown immediately，so I can't capture the error,but when I reset the JDK Environment Variables，then the other day it's ok.so maybe that is the point.

Comment: You can check the actual error by going to repository/logs/wso2carbon.log and get more details on what actually causing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on wso2server.bat and if it is disappearing, then that means there is an error executing the wso2server.bat.

Therefore, do not execute wso2server.bat by clicking on it. Just open a separate command prompt (Run -> cmd.exe), change directory (cd) to CARBON_HOME\bin, type wso2server.bat and press enter.

Then you will able to see if there is an error executing the wso2server.bat.

Most probably you might have an error with JAVA_HOME environment variable.